# Gedit hangs and crashes

Tags: gedit

While typing in Gedit(Ubuntu 14.01) it occasionally hangs,the mouse arrow flickers and then it crashes without any error message(it just closes),causing great trouble.
I am normally using Gedit alongwith browser window and terminal. I have a 4gigabytes RAM and a 10GB swap partition. I have my system dual booted with Ubuntu and Windows 8.1.

The output for top :

```
top - 15:12:47 up  3:40,  2 users,  load average: 1.36, 1.42, 2.16
Tasks: 221 total,   3 running, 218 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 16.3 us,  9.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 74.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   3913664 total,  2364424 used,  1549240 free,   127292 buffers
KiB Swap:  9765884 total,        0 used,  9765884 free.  1236420 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
 5629 rishabh   20   0  585768  34572  25616 R  37.5  0.9   0:05.70 gnome-term+ 
 1601 root      20   0  522404 124312  71288 R  28.1  3.2  38:10.79 Xorg        
 2315 rishabh   20   0 1549732 156324  60808 S  18.7  4.0  17:10.09 compiz      
 4960 rishabh   20   0 1207420 348412  84200 S   9.4  8.9   8:15.20 firefox     
    1 root      20   0   29564   4320   2584 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.80 init        
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd    
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.11 ksoftirqd/0 
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+ 
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:09.93 rcu_sched   
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.22 rcuos/0     
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.86 rcuos/1     
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:06.77 rcuos/2     
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.75 rcuos/3     
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuos/4     
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuos/5     
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuos/6     
   15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuos/7     
   16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh      
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+
```

The output for   `free --human&&lsb_release -s -c` :

```
rishabh@rishabh-Inspiron-3521:~$ free --human&&lsb_release -s -c
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3.7G       2.2G       1.5G       245M       124M       1.2G
-/+ buffers/cache:       916M       2.8G
Swap:         9.3G         0B       9.3G
utopic

rishabh@rishabh-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo df --human

[sudo] password for rishabh: 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda10       55G  4.8G   48G  10% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           383M  1.1M  382M   1% /run
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            1.9G  632K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   80K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda11       63G   50G  9.7G  84% /home
/dev/sda1       496M   54M  443M  11% /boot/efi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your RAM, CPU, Disk or swap.

In the following lines the `2> /dev/null` just means "ignore any errors"

1. Make a full [system backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)  (You're user type 4)
2. `sudo apt-get purge gedit`
3. `sudo rm -r ~/.local/share/gedit/* 2> /dev/null`
4. `sudo rm -r /usr/lib/gedit/* 2> /dev/null`
5. `sudo rm -r /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.gedit.plugins.* 2> /dev/null`
6. `sudo apt-get install gedit`

gets rid of anything that can cause stability problems in `gedit` and then re-installs it.